# Hash Tag Links not Overlap responsive floating header CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a floating header that resizes when windows size changes. I also have # links that scroll to the corresponding part of the website; the headers shouldnt overlap the destination of the # link.
I accomplished that using CSS using this code:

```
:target:before {
content:"";
display:block;
height:250px; /* fixed header height . with 250 it works for desktop.*/ 
margin:-250px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height . 250 also here */
}
```

The problem is that since the header is responsive and resizes, it doesnt work fine when you use the links in smaller devices.

What should I add to this CSS code to trigger different versions depending on the window size?

Thanks

Comment: You should use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to adapt your CSS to multiple configurations

Answer (score 0):

Without using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), using a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) is your next option.

For example, if you wanted your css to react differently on a screen that is 1920px across versus a screen that is 1280px across, your CSS might look like this:

```
media screen min-width: 1920px {
  :target:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:250px;  
    margin:-250px 0 0;
  }
}

media screen min-width: 1280px {
  :target:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:125px;  
    margin:-125px 0 0;
  }
}
```